# airflow db init error in WSL2 Ubuntu: "Additional properties are not allowed ('logo' was unexpected)"

Tags: airflow, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have the next visualization of the error:

```
  File "/home/tinmar/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jsonschema/validators.py", line 353, in validate
    raise error
jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError: Additional properties are not allowed ('**logo**' was unexpected)


Failed validating 'additionalProperties' in schema['properties']['integrations']['items']:
    {'additionalProperties': False,
     'properties': {'external-doc-url': {'description': 'URL to external '
                                                        'documentation for '
                                                        'the integration.',
                                         'type': 'string'},
                    'how-to-guide': {'description': 'List of paths to '
                                                    'how-to-guide for the '
                                                    'integration. The path '
                                                    'must start with '
                                                    "'/docs/'",
                                     'items': {'type': 'string'},
                                     'type': 'array'},
                    'integration-name': {'description': 'Name of the '
                                                        'integration.',
                                         'type': 'string'},
                    'tags': {'description': 'List of tags describing the '
                                            "integration. While we're "
                                            'using RST, only one tag is '
                                            'supported per integration.',
                             'items': {'enum': ['apache',
                                                'aws',
                                                'azure',
                                                'gcp',
                                                'gmp',
                                                'google',
                                                'protocol',
                                                'service',
                                                'software',
                                                'yandex'],
                                       'type': 'string'},
                             'maxItems': 1,
                             'minItems': 1,
                             'type': 'array'}},
     'required': ['integration-name', 'external-doc-url', 'tags'],
     'type': 'object'}

On instance['integrations'][0]:
    {'external-doc-url': 'https://www.sqlite.org/index.html',
     'how-to-guide': ['/docs/apache-airflow-providers-sqlite/operators.rst'],
     'integration-name': 'SQLite',
     **'logo': '/integration-logos/sql**,
     'tags': ['software']}
```

I really don't know what the hell is happen here, I tried almost every solution I can find in the internet but nothing was usefull...

By the way, before this error, I have other one:

'''
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms.compat'
'''

Error that was solved by this code

```
pip install wtforms==2.3.3
pip install marsmallow==3.0.0
```

I think that maybe the first error was the cause of all, but I'm not sure about it and I don't know how can be possible

This errors came when I try to uninstall airflow 2.5.0 in order to downgrade to airflow 2.0.0. I mean, this was the cause of the other two errors, I think so...

I also try to uninstall and reinstall WSL2, this threw me some errors but I solve it, I don't think this was the problem because before I trying this, the other errors already pop out.

I expect a local airflow env in Ubuntu with WSL2

I will appreciate if someone have any idea on how to solve it, thank you before it :)